# jQuery custom click

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do the following:

```
$("#something ."+id).click(function() {
    callFunction(id,message);
});     

$("#something ."+id).silentclick(function() {
    callFunction(id,message,'silent');
});
```

But silentclick gives an error saying function does not exist. How do I go about creating my own custom event like silentclick?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What exactly are you supposed to do? The "click" property lets you put a function call when the user clicks an element, isn't that enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are trying to create a custom event. If this is the case, you can use either .bind() or .live().

```
$("#something ."+id).bind('silentclick',function() {    
  callFunction(id,message,'silent');
});
```

Then, you could fire the event from somewhere else in your code.

```
$("#something ."+id).trigger('silentclick');
```

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it by 30 seconds :(

Answer (score 3):

You extend jQuery like this:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.silentclick = function(action) {
        /* do what you like with the function passed */
        action(); /* for example invoke the function */
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Without knowing what silentclick wants to do or how you want it triggered, I can't really give any more detail.